# Creating dynamic urls in codeigniter

Tags: controller, routes, seo, codeigniter-2, clean-urls

I am currently making a small CMS for a news agency. The admin will update the news in a interval of time. Now I want the `url` to be look like `http://somedomain.com/apple-iphoe5c-released`, not like `http://somedomain.com/top-news/1`. I have seen in `gocart` ( built in codeigniter ) , they have the url with the product name . How I am able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this thing you have use the routes in ci which are as given

Consider the small example

```
$route['aboutus'] = "any controller is map to that name";
```

samplesite.com/aboutus [aboutus is controller] samplesite.com/contactus [contactus is controller]

```
$route['memberaccount/(:num)'] = "any controller is map to that name/$1";
```

samplesite.com/memberaccount/32

if still not getting try the above link https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html